# Task.Run(), passing parameter to

Tags: c#, asynchronous, concurrency, task

Consider the following code:

```
attempt = 0;
for (int counter = 0; counter < 8; counter++)
{
    if (attempt < totalitems)
    {
        Tasklist<output>.Add(Task.Run(() =>
        {
            return someasynctask(inputList[attempt]);
        }));
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
    attempt++;
}
await Task.WhenAll(Tasklist).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I want to have for example 8 concurrent tasks, each working on different inputs concurrently, and finally check the result, when all of them have finished.
Because I'm not awaiting for completion of `Task.Run()` `attempt` is increased before starting of tasks, and when the task is started, there may be items in the `inputList` that are not processed or processed twice or more instead (because of uncertainty in `attempt` value.

How to do that?

Comment: You should provide a MCVE... anyway, as I understand what you are telling, your problem is the variable `attempt` doesn't have the expected value when you start the tasks, am I correct ?

Comment: PLINQ may help.

Comment: Yes, You are correct! attempt value is changed more sooner than starting the task @gobes

Comment: Isn't it a problem related to closures? Take a look here: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @gobes for his answer:

Try this:

```
attempt = 0;
for (int counter = 0; counter < 8; counter++)
{
    if (attempt < totalitems)
    {
        Tasklist<output>.Add(Task.Run(() =>
        {
            int tmpAttempt = attempt;
            return someasynctask(inputList[tmpAttempt]);
        }));
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
    attempt++;
}
await Task.WhenAll(Tasklist).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Actually, what the compiler is doing is extracting your lambda into a method, located in an automagically generated class, which is referencing the attempt variable. This is the important point: the generated code only reference the variable from another class; it doesn't copy it. So every change to attempt is seen by the method.

What happens during the execution is roughly this:

enter the loop with attempt = 0
add a call of the lambda-like-method to your tasklist
increase attempt
repeat
After the loop, you have some method calls awaiting (no pun intended) to be executed, but each one is referencing THE SAME VARIABLE, therefore sharing its value - the last affected to it.

For more details, I really recommend reading C# in depth, or some book of the same kind - there are a lot of resources about closure in C# on the web :)

Comment: int tmpAttempt = attempt; should be above Task.Run, right? bad bug for someone who stumbles here, better scroll to next answer.

Comment: ***THIS ANSWER IS WRONG***. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/271440/903600).

Answer (score 5):

The problem lies within the use of a "lambda": when `Task.Run(() => return someasynctask(inputList[attempt]));` is reached during the execution, the variable `attempt` is captured, not its value (i.e. it is a "closure"). Consequently, when the lambda gets executed, the value of the variable at that specific moment will be used.

Just add a temporary copy of the variable before your lambda, and use that. E.g.

```
if (attempt < totalitems)
{
    int localAttempt = attempt;
    Tasklist<output>.Add(Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return someasynctask(inputList[localAttempt]);
    }));
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me how to do that?

Comment: I created a copy inside lambada, and it works now, but still a question? Do this solution work always, or maybe sometimes may be some inconsistency?

Comment: 'localAttempt' should be declared in the lambda itself to force the copy of the value; in your code there is still a closure problem.

Comment: I don't know what is closure problem :( There's a lot to read in the  csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx. I want a more simple tutorial @gobes